# Javascript and callbacks and defered. How can I run a function after a google gmail API request completes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have built up a javascript file that starts with:

```
var myApp = function () {

var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxx';
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly';
var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');

return {
```

The functions are declared like:

```
    getSent: function(callback) {
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      'userId': 'me',
      'labelIds': 'SENT',
      'maxResults': 10
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
      $.each(response.messages, function() {
        var messageRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
          'userId': 'me',
          'id': this.id
        });


        messageRequest.execute(myApp.appendMessageRow);
      });
    });
  },
```

And then  run through a single function that calls others:

```
myApp.init();
```

How can I defer a function to be run after my google request function getsent() has been fully completed. I have tried using callbacks to another function and it runs but it runs while the getsent() is still being executed. Can I use the jQuery method defered to run the callback when done?

I have tried: 
    myApp.getSent(myApp.gMailSyncComplete()); // Runs early

and I tried:
myApp.getSent().done(myApp.gMailSyncComplete()); // no jQuery done defined

Comment: You must pass the function value as the argument, not call the function immediately.

Comment: Your `getSent` method never calls its `callback`.

Comment: can you provide an example ... is this not what I am doing with myApp.getSent(myApp.gMailSyncComplete());

Comment: @Ryan here you can see how callBack should be call https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function e.g myApp.getSent(callback){
  //code of your func
  //call callback
callback();
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some important errors in your code:

- You are creating a function `getSent` that accepts a callback, but you are not calling the callback at all so it won't get executed ever. You should execute the callback when everything else is done.
- You are not waiting for all message requests to be completed. You can use a library like [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) which has the method [map](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) to be able to execute all requests in parallel and wait for all of them to be completed before calling the callback.

With these two things in mind, and using `async`, this would be an example of the resulting code:

```
getSent: function (callback) {
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
    'userId': 'me',
    'labelIds': 'SENT',
    'maxResults': 10
  })

  request.execute(function (response) {
    async.map(response.messages, function (msg, cb) {
        var messageRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
          'userId': 'me',
          'id': msg.id
        })

        messageRequest.execute(function (result) {
            myApp.appendMessageRow(result)
            cb()
        })
    }, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err
      callback()
    })
  })
}
```

- Lastly, when invoking this function, keep in mind that the `callback` parameter must be a function.

To make things clear, let's translate the code you wrote, `myApp.getSent(myApp.gMailSyncComplete())`, into an equivalent structure:

```
var callback = myApp.gMailSyncComplete()
myApp.getSent(callback)
```

When you do this, you are **not** passing **the function** but **the result of the function**, because you are executing it. That's why it gets executed immediately. The correct way to do this would be the following:

```
var callback = myApp.gMailSyncComplete
myApp.getSent(callback)
```

Or, in your one-liner example, `myApp.getSent(myApp.gMailSyncComplete)`

Comment: just a quick note about preserving state in callback: `myApp.gMailSyncComplete.bind(myApp)` to be sure that `this` would be useful

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain your comments. I have learned something today.

Comment: @Ryan you are welcome :) asynchronous operations in javascript has a bit of a steep learning curve, but once you understand the basics then you can explore all the different ways to implement such operations. I recommend you check out other ways to work with async functions like the `Promise` class, `async / await`, `bluebird`, `observables`, `streams` and other. I personally love all these tools! Best of luck

Answer (score 3):

you can use javascript promise.

```
    function testPromise() {  
    let p1 = new Promise(
        // The resolver function is called with the ability to resolve or
        // reject the promise
       (resolve, reject) => {
            /*your async function*/  
      }
    );
  // defined what to do when the promise is resolved with the then() call,
    // and what to do when the promise is rejected with the catch() call
    p1.then(
        // Log the fulfillment value
        function(val) {
            log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', val +
                ') Promise fulfilled (<small>Async code terminated</small>)<br/>');
        })
    .catch(
        // Log the rejection reason
       (reason) => {
            console.log('Handle rejected promise ('+reason+') here.');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery `promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/), check the example below.

```
getSent: function() {
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
  'userId': 'me',
  'labelIds': 'SENT',
  'maxResults': 10
});

request.execute(function(response) {
  $.each(response.messages, function() {
    var messageRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
      'userId': 'me',
      'id': this.id
    });


    messageRequest.execute(myApp.appendMessageRow);
  });
});
},
...
$.when( myApp.getSent() ).done(function() {
    // do whatever you want in here as callback
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Inside of your getSent function create a jQuery Deferred object and return a promise. Then after request.execute has finished you can call resolve/reject. I created a small snippet to show example. Maybe you can modify to fit your needs

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i =0;

    function getText() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            i++;
            deferred.resolve("text " + i);
        }, 3000);
        return deferred.promise();
    }
    getText().then(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
    }).then(function () {
        getText().then(function (value2) {
            console.log(value2);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks for putting the time into answering. Your answer isnt in the format that I have had in the question its just a normal jQuery. I'm trying to avoid setTimeout and rather have it finished after all 10 calls as this value  may change to say 500 in the future etc. I'm not sure why you were downvoted, but my question was also downvoted without reason.

Comment: ok. i only put a setTimeout to demonstrate the deferred functionality. I personally do not use setTimeout in my applications.

Comment: @JohnDover It does remove one reputation point to the user that gives the downvote